# Line buffering in a bash coproc

Tags: bash, buffering, coproc

I'm trying to use a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) `coproc` and I'm running into difficulties, most likely with buffering.  I have a complex command which accepts line-oriented input from stdin and prints a line to stdout, per line of input.  At the command-line this command works fine on a per-line basis, but when I put it in a coproc and read from the `${COPROC[0]}` FD, the read blocks.

I can recreate this behavior with `paste`, but not with `cat`.  I expect `paste` and `cat` to pretty much do the same thing when passed no parameters.  This is the case when running directly at the command prompt:

```
$ cat
Hello World!<RETURN>
Hello World!^D
$ paste
Hello World!<RETURN>
Hello World!^D
$
```

(`RETURN` and `^D` added for illustration)

But when I put these in a [coproc](/questions/tagged/coproc), they behave differently - `cat` is strictly line-buffered, whereas `paste` appears to be operating with a much larger buffer:

```
$ coproc cat
$ echo 'Hello world!' >&${COPROC[1]}
$ read -ru ${COPROC[0]} line; echo $line
Hello world!
$ kill $COPROC_PID
[3]+  Terminated              coproc COPROC cat
$ 
$ coproc paste
[3] 42657
$ echo 'Hello world!' >&${COPROC[1]}
$ read -ru ${COPROC[0]} line; echo $line
#### read blocks here until ^C ####
```

I think the reason for this is that `paste` adjusts its buffering mode, depending on what it is connected to, whereas `cat` is always in line-buffering mode.

Is there any way to force `paste` (or other general command) to be line buffered in the coproc?

---

After a bit more experimentation I found I can recreate similar behavior without [coproc](/questions/tagged/coproc)s and instead just piping between `cat` and `paste`:

```
$ cat | cat
Hello World!<RETURN>
Hello World!^D
$ cat | paste
Hello World!<RETURN>
Hello World!^D
$ paste | cat
Hello World!<RETURN>
#### command blocks here until ^C ####
```

(`RETURN` and `^D` added for illustration)

- First we pipe `cat` to `cat` and get line buffering all the way though
- Next we pipe `cat` to `paste` and also get line buffering all the way though
- Lastly we pipe `paste` to `cat` and don't get line buffering

This appears to indicate that `paste` will line buffer its stdout when in interactive mode, but otherwise it will use a much bigger buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to force line-buffering is to use the `stdbuf` coreutils tool, if available:

*[`stdbuf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) allows one to modify the buffering operations of the three standard I/O streams associated with a program*.

For the `coproc` case:

```
$ coproc stdbuf -oL paste
[3] 42751
$ echo 'Hello world!' >&${COPROC[1]}
$ read -ru ${COPROC[0]} line; echo $line
Hello world!
$ kill $COPROC_PID
[3]+  Terminated              coproc COPROC stdbuf -oL paste
$
```

For the simple pipe of `paste` to `cat` case:

```
$ stdbuf -oL paste | cat
Hello World!<RETURN>
Hello World!^D
$
```